# Ionic 4 Loading Local resource not working on IOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic4

I'm trying to load a image from users phone, crop it and then display. Im using the webview plugin to do that. It works as intended on android but not on IOS.

I've tried this from another question, which resloves to file not found error

```
itemSrc = itemSrc.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
```

I also looked at NormalizeURL but that does not seem to work with Ionic 4

Heres some code

```
 this.imagePicker.getPictures(options)
     .then((results: string[]) => {
           results.forEach(res => {
              this.crop.crop(res, {quality: 50})
              .then(
                data =>{
//this is extracting the URL
this.user.photos.push(this.webview.convertFileSrc(data));
},
```

After that, the UI should display the cropped image, which it does on android, but not on IOS.

I used safari dev tools to inspect and this is the error:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: unsupported URL (unsafe:ionic://localhost/_app_file_/Users/radmac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8E6A6BFA-66FA-4DB3-B556-BCE9E2EFE33A/data/Containers/Data/Application/C39D8D99-0F67-4D33-9195-EE2B4D4E4707/tmp/cdv_photo_024.jpg, line 0)
```

Comment: You should try using angular DomSanitizer bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution for this. Before that, You can read this blog post which is really helpful if you want to understand more about ionic native and images.
https://ionicframework.com/blog/storing-photos-with-the-cordova-camera-and-file-plugins/

the solution was to just wrap the webview converted src with dom sanitizer, like so,

```
 const resolvedImg = this.webview.convertFileSrc(data);
 this.user.photos.push(<string>this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(resolvedImg));
```

Make sure to import the dom sanitizer.

```
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";

...

 constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
 ...
 }
```